# There is no output after changing Utf8 format

Tags: react-native

```
const token = res.data.access_Token;  

const decodedData = jwt_decode(token);  

const encryptedPhoneNumber = decodedData.PhoneNumber; 
const privateKey = 'smth';  

const decryptedPhoneNumber = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedPhoneNumber,    privateKey).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);  

console.log(decryptedPhoneNumber);
```

Firstly, I decoded the API token and then I have to decrypt the claims using the encrypted key. But finally no output in seen in the console after decrypting. I want to get the original form which is decrypted form.

Please help me with this problem.